# Connect to multiple sql servers on ssms launch

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to automate the launch of SSMS to automatically load my Solution file and connect to two servers.

I have the file bit working, but can only make it connect to one server.

I use the -S parameter in the command line, but when I use more than one, it only uses the end one.

Is there a way to use -S to connect to multiple servers?

Code:
`c:\ssms.exe -E -S myServer\myInstance -S myOtherServer\OtherInsance 
"c:\mySol.ssmssln"`

Comment: No you cant connect two serves at a time through SSMS,but there are other ways like using SQLCMD as a workaround.

-s accepts only a single parameter.Your best would be to use SQLCMD to change server in your solution where needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use SQLCMD please.  All I want is that when I open SSMS, two servers are open in Object Explorer

Comment: Check out this article.https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/

Comment: @TheGameiswar I don't think `SQLCMD` is what OP and I looking for. We don't want to `query` multiple Sql Server instances. We want `SSMS` to open 2 connections to 2 different Sql Server instances and show those instances in `Object Explorer`

Comment: @RoLYroLLs .I understood it differently then based on his code

Comment: @TheGameiswar no worries =)

Answer (score 3):

Check SSMSBoost add-in that I develop. It allows to auto-connect servers during start-up, also it has "Workspaces" - lists of documents with connections, that can be loaded with 1 click. Restore previous session is also included.

Comment: Wow nice add-in. Seems cool, but currently, I just want something small, even if it's a `bat` or `powershell` script that opens SSMS open the 2 (or more) server instances. =)